# how to converte an 4-input and 4-output system from state space to a transfer function matrix?

Tags: matlab, state-space, control-theory, transfer-function

I was trying to convert using the command `ss2tf` but the sintax of this command shows where to type the number of inputs of the system, but not the number of outputs. Nevertheless I tried to obtain my matrix transfer function with

`[num,den]=ss2tf(Ac,Bc,Cc,Dc,4)` where '4' it's the number of inputs.

As a result, the vector "num" has 4x9 dimension and my vector "den" has 1x9 dimension, so I got an error using

`F=tf(num,den)`

because "den" should have 4x9 dimension aswell.

So, is there another way to obtain transfer function from state space (with the option of including number of inputs and outputs)??

obs: the dimmensions of Ac, Bc, Cc and Dc are, respectively, 8x8; 8x4, 4x8 and 4x4.

edit: figured it out how to solve it. There's an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I should do it. The code is self explaining.

```
clear all;
close all;
clc;

% Generate random state-space system
sys = rss(2,2,2);

%% Generate transfer function matrix with Matlab tf
% For each output
for i = 1:size(sys,1)

    % For each input
    for j = 1:size(sys,2)

        % Get SISO transfer function
        [num,den] = ss2tf(sys(i,j).A,sys(i,j).B,sys(i,j).C,sys(i,j).D);

        % Compute tf
        Gtf(i,j) = tf(num,den);
    end
end

%% Generate transfer function matrix symbolic
% Laplace variable
s = sym('s');

% For each output
for i = 1:size(sys,1)

    % For each input
    for j = 1:size(sys,2)

        % Get SISO transfer function
        [num,den] = ss2tf(sys(i,j).A,sys(i,j).B,sys(i,j).C,sys(i,j).D);

        % Compute tf
        Gsym(i,j) = poly2sym(num,s);
    end
end

% Den is the same for all elements
Gsym = Gsym / poly2sym(den,s);

% Numeric vectors is transformed to symbolic vector, to make everything
% readable change the variable precision arithmetic to 4 digits for output
pretty(vpa(Gsym,4))
```

-Edit- I have to say that I am actually a bit surprised that Matlab does not have this functionality incorporated in the function `ss2tf` itself.

Answer (score 1):

If your system has `p` inputs and `q` outputs, then the tranfer function matrix `G(s)` has `p` lines and `q`columns. Each element pq of `G(s)` is a SISO transfer function with respect to entrie `p` and output `q`.

Let `n` be the system order. So, if you enter with `[b,a] = ss2tf(A,B,C,D,1)` you will get `b` with dimension `qx(n+1)` and `a` with dimension `1x(n+1)`. To obtain the element 1x1 of `G(s)`, you have to obtain the SISO transfer function from the first line of `b` and the vector `a`. Similarly, for the element 1x2, you have to obtain the transfer function from the second line of `b` and the vector `a`. After you obtain the transfer functions using all lines of `b` you will have the first line of `G(s)`.

For the other lines you have to enter `[b,a] = ss2tf(A,B,C,D,2)` (and obtain all SISO transfer functions again), then do `[b,a] = ss2tf(A,B,C,D,3)` and so on.

Finally, use matrix concatenation to obtain the compact form of `G(s)`, like:

`G_s=[g11 g12 g13 ... g1q;g21 g22 ..g2q; ....;gp1 gp2 .. gpq]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you misunderstood the syntax of the function. Here's what the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ss2tf.html) says:

> `[b,a] = ss2tf(A,B,C,D)` converts a state-space representation of a
>   system into an equivalent transfer function. `ss2tf` returns the
>   Laplace-transform transfer function for continuous-time systems and
>   the Z-transform transfer function for discrete-time systems. `[b,a] =
>   ss2tf(A,B,C,D,ni)` returns the transfer function that results when the
>   `n`ith input of a system with multiple inputs is excited by a unit
>   impulse.

So you don't need to specify the number of inputs/outputs, they are implied by the respective sizes of your state-space matrices. Use the first syntax and you should be fine.

Comment: actually, I cannot use the first syntax in this case, because it leads to the error:

''Error using ss2tf (line 26)
IU must be specified for systems with **more than one input**.

Error in bode (line 5)
[num,den]=ss2tf(Ac,Bc,Cc,Dc);''

Comment: OK, well then you need to loop through your inputs with a `for` loop and do one input at a time using the second syntax. You will then end up with `n` transfer functions where `n` is the number of inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `tf2ss` or `ss2tf`. You just can use

```
G_s = tf(G);
```

directly converting from one system representation to the other.